# create a public Google Cloud image (or machineImage)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, gcloud

I published a gene mapping pipeline that can be downloaded from Github and run on a local machine. The problem is that server setting is not always available (or easy) to people. I created an instance and an image (or machineImage which I don't understand the difference) on Google cloud that can run the pipeline, however I could not make it public so people can use it to create an instance, upload their specific data (fastq files) and run it to map their mutants.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You cannot make an image public except by setting yourself up in Google Marketplace. You can grant individual users permission to use the image. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images

Comment: Thanks; I tried this:

     gcloud compute images add-iam-policy-binding simple-gcloud-machnieimage --member='user:USER_NAME@gmail.com' --role='roles/compute.imageUser'

but received the following error message:

     ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.add-iam-policy-binding) HTTPError 404: The resource 'projects/PROJECT_NAME/global/images/simple-gcloud-machnieimage' was not found

My image is under Compute images>machine images

Answer (score 0):

As John Hanley mentioned, you cannot make an image public.

According to the official documentation:

[Compute Engine Images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images)

> Public images are provided and maintained by Google, open source
> communities, and third-party vendors. By default, all Google Cloud
> projects have access to these images and can use them to create
> instances.

Therefore you can use the public images maintained by Google to create your instances.